# Mobile-like Autocomplete for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

One area I feel mobile keyboards excel over their physical counterparts is the ability to autocomplete, autocorrect, and offer word predictions. Yet it feels like something similar should be achievable relatively easily with a browser extension, yet I am having the hardest time finding *anything* relevant. Does anyone know if such a tool exists?

Comment: Are you talking about just for the fact of typing? Or autocomplete for things like addresses and card information?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Didn't even know this SE existed. I'll go there.

Answer (score -2):

Chrome does that (in the Omnibox), on PCs.

It is a setting, under the heading 'Privacy'; lines 2 (use a prediction service to help complete...) and 6 (use a web service to help resolve spelling errors).

Comment: Which setting exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound , I added them to the answer.

Comment: I was looking for word prediction for regular typing. Not form fill or Omnibox.

Comment: @Argent , You asked for 'auto-complete for chrome', not 'word-prediction for regular typing'. Thanks for punishing me for answering what you asked and not what you thought.

Comment: Actually, as you can see in this screenshot, I've never up- nor downvoted you. But thanks for assuming I am an ass. http://i.imgur.com/GYWQCdB.png